# 'where a death has been,' 'where has been a death,' 'where there has been a death'?

Tags: grammar

Which one of these sentences is grammatically correct? I would really appreciate it if the reason were presented.

> (A) It is a very old custom, in some areas, to stop the clocks  in a
>   house **where has been a death**.
>   (B) It is a very old custom, in
>   some areas, to stop the clocks  in a house **where  a death has
>   been**.
>   (C) It is a very old custom, in some areas, to stop the
>   clocks in a house **where  there has been a death**.

Comment: Can you show some effort? Why do you think this question is difficult? What would your answer be, and why?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you could say.

"It is an old custom to stop the clocks in a house where there has been a death." is the most right of the three.

"It is an old custom to stop the clocks in a house where a death has occurred." would also work. or "in a house where someone died."

Try moving the sentence around. 
"Someone died in this house." is the same as "In this house, someone died." It is just active/passive voice.

Comment: I think B is marginal but acceptable, although it sounds slightly archaic -- which makes me think this is a poor question all-around.  And of course OP should have shown some supporting guesses or research.